# Firebase A/B test stops after some seconds

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-ab-testing

We are trying to perform an A/B-test on our Android app using firebase remote config.

The problem is after some seconds the test stops automatically without any error message... just saying "No leader found".

We added a test device to the test and for these seconds we see the correct variant on the device. So it seems the test works correctly. Furthermore we performed some A/B tests successfully... so firebase should works correct too.

Maybe there is a problem with the goals?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your data sharing is turned on, the current flow when data sharing is off is not very intuitive